# Web Scraping - XPath - Find all elements of specific tag in div

Tags: wordpress, xpath, web-scraping, domxpath

I am using "Scrapes" wordpress plugin.

I want to extract all paragraphs from specific div.

```
<div id="main" class="col-md-9 col-sm-8">
 <div class="inside-post"> 
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Three</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Below code is returning only first item:

```
//div[@id="main"]/div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " inside-post ")]/p[1]

One
```

But I want all of three:

```
One
Two 
Three
```

Kindly help on it. Advance Thanks.

Comment: Just to let you know that your XML example doesn't help with the XPath you posted, since your XPath expects another `div` with an id of `main` as a parent of the `div` in your example. It's always best to post XML examples that actually work with the XPath you're asking about.

Comment: I think that was not necessary. Its understandable.

Comment: It is necessary if you want people to be sure of your problem. Also, please add more information to your question because the XPath I gave you in my answer returns all 3 `p` elements.

Comment: Your code not returning all elements. Thanks. And do not downgrade questions of anyone, if your answer is not accepted by other.

Comment: I'm trying to help - the XPath I've given selects all three `p` elements in the XML example you have provided. If you're still only getting the first one then the issue probably lies elsewhere - e.g. how you're actually using this XPath. Without that information it's difficult to know what your problem is, so if you add more details to your question it will help people to help you.

Comment: I have added all the necessary things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180511/discussion-between-matt-jones-and-asad-rao).

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath specifically selects the first element - `/p[1]`. If you remove the `[1]` then you should select all `p` elements.

Try

```
//div[@id="main"]/div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " inside-post ")]/p
```

Comment: I tried that thing already. This code also returns only first element.

Comment: In which case, you need to give us more information. The XPath I have posted works. How are accessing the returned node list?

Comment: If this (correct, +1) answer isn't helping, then OP's problem has to do with how the results of the XPath are being processed.  Asad Rao: See duplicate link for further details.  It talks about text nodes rather than elements, but the concept is the same:  Functions (in XPath and in hosting languages) often take the first node of a nodeset.  This should be your first suspicion when you're certain that your XPath is selecting multiple nodes yet you're not seeing them.